# Freeform 4.0.12 and Multiple Recipients

Tags: solspace-freeform

OK - I need some fresh eyes on this as I think it all looks correct but I'm not getting emails coming through.

- Freeform 4.0.12
- EE 2.6.1
- CP-generated email coming through fine
- Form entries appearing in FreeForm CP

Goals:

- Multiple recipients based on selected checkboxes
- Defaulting checkbox choice based on URL
- Selected names/appearing in the notification email

Template Code:

```
 {exp:freeform:form
form:id="contact-form"
form_name="contact" 
required="name|email"
return="contact/thanks"
recipients="yes"
recipient_limit="10"
recipient_template="to_era" 
recipient1="recipient1|email1@email.com"
recipient2="recipient2|email2@email.com"
recipient3="recipient3|email3@email.com"
recipient4="recipient4|email4@email.com"
recipient5="recipient5|email5@email.com"
recipient6="recipient6|email6@email.com"
recipient7="recipient7|email7@email.com"
recipient8="recipient8|email8@email.com"
recipient9="recipient9|email9@email.com"
recipient10="recipient10|email10@email.com"
}



<p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40" maxlength="64" value="" class="textfield" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40" maxlength="128" value="" class="textfield" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" size="40" maxlength="16" value="" class="textfield" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="availability">What is the best time for us to reach you?</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="availability" name="availability" size="40" value="" class="textfield" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40" class="textfield"></textarea>
  </p>

  <fieldset id="community_checkboxes">
      <legend>Select each of the communities are you interested in.</legend>

        <p> {!-- ravenna --}
           <input{if segment_2=="ravenna"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value1}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value1}">{freeform:recipient_name1}</label>
        </p>

        <p> 
           <input{if segment_2=="wallingford"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value2}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value2}">{freeform:recipient_name2}</label>
        </p>

          <p> {!--lakeshore--}
           <input{if segment_2=="north-seattle"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value3}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value3}">{freeform:recipient_name3}</label>
        </p>

        <p> {!-- broadview --}
           <input{if segment_2=="mercer-island"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value4}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value4}">{freeform:recipient_name4}</label>
        </p>

        <p> {!--wallingford --}
           <input{if segment_2=="lakeshore"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value5}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value5}">{freeform:recipient_name5}</label>
        </p>

        <p> {!-- mercer-island --}
           <input{if segment_2=="issaquah"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value6}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value6}">{freeform:recipient_name6}</label>
        </p>

        <p> {!--issaquah --}
           <input{if segment_2=="broadview"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value7}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value7}">{freeform:recipient_name7}</label>
        </p>

        <p> {!--bellevue --}
           <input{if segment_2=="bellevue"} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value8}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value8}">{freeform:recipient_name8}</label>
        </p>

         <p> 
           <input type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value10}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value10}">{freeform:recipient_name10}</label>
        </p>        

        <p> 
           <input{if segment_2==""} checked{/if} type="checkbox" id="{freeform:recipient_value9}" class="community_chbx" value="" name="recipient_email[]">
           <label for="{freeform:recipient_value9}">{freeform:recipient_name9}</label>
        </p>



  </fieldset>

  <p><input id="button_submit" name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit Form' /></p>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: The data being captured in the module? Just the email not coming through?

Comment: Yes - the submissions appear in the Freeform CP, just no email.

Comment: Are you sure the server sends email OK?

Comment: Yep - at least using the Communicate tab.

Comment: OK, cool.  And your `recipient_template` works?

Comment: Solspace got it..;)

Comment: heh, that works ;)  enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting value="{freeform:recipient_value1}, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have recipient1 repeated as a param rather than recipient1, recipient2, etc.  May be nothing, or that may be it.

Comment: Yea, I had to pull the actual email addresses out and that was a copy/paste error. The actual code isn't that way.

Comment: Nuts. I thought that might have been it, as I have known freeform to behave peculiarly when a double parameter is present.  The rest of the code looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since data is hitting Freeform but emails aren't arriving, the first thing to test is whether or not emails from EE are being delivered correctly. Test this by sending an email to yourself from the Communicate page (Tools >> Communicate).

If the email arrives, I'd conclude it's an issue in your template.

If the email doesn't arrive, I'd conclude the issue is with email delivery.

One way to test the actual delivery is to connect EE to an SMTP account... either your own or a free http://www.mandrill.com account. You can make this adjustment at (Admin >> Email Configuration). Select SMTP from the Email Protocol dropdown and add your credentials in the fields below.